# Change default apple ID for xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10.1

Consider `myAppleID@gmail.com` and `otherAppleID@gmail.com` as Apple IDs.
`otherAppleID@gmail.com` is the default apple id for my Xcode. How can I make `myAppleID@gmail.com` as default.?

Comment: I think delete `otherAppleID@gmail.com` account from xcode then add again

Comment: How exactly is this related to Swift or iOS?

Comment: I'm trying to upload app to AppStore. but the Application loader does not show my apple id.

Answer (score 1):

On Xcode menu -> preferences -> accounts:

- On the Apple IDs list, click on (+).
- Select the type of account you would like to add:
- Sing in with your ID

Then in your Project properties -> General Tab -> Signing section:

- Automatically manage signing should be checked
- Select your Team account on the Team listing. (If you can't find it
  there, click add account again).

It should be your default account now.